# How to find builds triggered via svn commit

Tags: svn, teamcity

I am fairly new to Teamcity. I have a project setup in Teamcity with more than 100 build configurations many of which are dependent on each other. I create a setup executable file for the project from all these build configurations.

Considering a scenario where there is an upgrade to the product and only few components are changed, I need only those changed components in the setup. I want to identify the builds triggered due to SVN commits and not via dependency triggers. I want to use artifacts from SVN build triggers only.

Is there a way where I can find the builds triggered via SVN commit and include only these builds in the setup to create executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to figure out how the build is triggered. You can do this by using the parameter `teamcity.build.triggeredBy`. I have added following `Command Line` build step. The Following code will check if the build was triggered via SVN Commit.

```
IF "%teamcity.build.triggeredBy%" == "Subversion" (
    FOR %%I IN (%system.paths.artifacts%) DO COPY %%I %system.out.artifacts% /y
)
```

You will have to define the `system.paths.artifacts` as `System Properties`. Following are few examples.

- "bin\Release\MyDLL.dll" "bin\Release\MYDLL.dll.config" "bin\Release\MYEXE.exe"
- "C:\Output\MyDLL.dll" "C:\Output\MYDLL.dll.config"
- "......\Output\MyDLL.dll" "......\Output\MYDLL.dll.config" "......\Output\MYEXE.exe"

Also define `system.out.artifacts` which is the destination directory where you want to copy the artifacts. Examples

- "C:\Temp\Setup"

Answer (score 0):

If it is a one time search, you can go into the Audit page (Administration -> Audit) and figure out the builds triggerred by SVN commits and not dependency triggers.

Comment: Thanks Biswajit_86, But I want to do this while the build is running.